# Warning: mkdir(): File exists in

Tags: php

Hola quiero hacer una pregunta, estoy trabajando con php en su version 8 quiero que el usuario pueda actualizar su foto de perfil, nombre y contraseña lo hacen sin problema pero con la foto si tengo muchos problemas porque si la sube pero cuando quiero actualizarla sale este error

Hola quiero hacer una pregunta, estoy trabajando con php en su version 8 quiero que el usuario pueda actualizar su foto de perfil, nombre y contraseña lo hacen sin problema pero con la foto si tengo muchos problemas porque si la sube pero cuando quiero actualizarla sale este error

> Warning
> : mkdir(): File exists in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\turnapp\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php
> on line
> 545

la linea 545 es esta

```
                if(!empty($_POST["fotoActual"])){

                    unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);

                }else{

                    mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                }
```

en la vista tengo esto

```
 <div class="form-group tex-center">
              
              <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO</div>

              <input type="file" class="nuevaFoto" name="editarFoto">

              <p class="help-block">Peso máximo de la foto 2MB</p>

                <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION["foto"]; ?>" width="20%" class="img-cuadre">

           

              <input type="hidden" name="fotoActual" id="fotoActual">



            </div>
```

y en mi controlador esto

```
static public function editarPerfilController(){
    
    $ruta = "";

        if(isset($_POST["editarUsuario"])){ 

            /*=============================================
                VALIDAR IMAGEN
                =============================================*/

                $ruta = $_POST["fotoActual"];

                if(isset($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"])){

                    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

                    $nuevoAncho = 500;
                    $nuevoAlto = 500;

                    /*=============================================
                    CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO DONDE VAMOS A GUARDAR LA FOTO DEL USUARIO
                    =============================================*/

                    $directorio = "vistas/img/perfiles/perfil/".$_POST["editarUsuario"];

                    /*=============================================
                    PRIMERO PREGUNTAMOS SI EXISTE OTRA IMAGEN EN LA BD
                    =============================================*/

                    if(!empty($_POST["fotoActual"])){

                        unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);

                    }else{

                        mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                    }   

                    /*=============================================
                    DE ACUERDO AL TIPO DE IMAGEN APLICAMOS LAS FUNCIONES POR DEFECTO DE PHP
                    =============================================*/

                    if($_FILES["editarFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){

                        /*=============================================
                        GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
                        =============================================*/

                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);

                        $ruta = "vistas/img/perfiles/perfil/".$_POST["editarUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";

                        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                       

                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

                        imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);

                    }

                    if($_FILES["editarFoto"]["type"] == "image/png"){

                        /*=============================================
                        GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
                        =============================================*/

                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);

                        $ruta = "vistas/img/perfiles/perfil/".$_POST["editarUsuario"]."/".$aleatorio.".png";

                        $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);                        

                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

                        imagepng($destino, $ruta);

                    }

                }
```

Comment: aqui da el error  if(!empty($_POST["fotoActual"])){

                        unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);

                    }else{

                        mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                    }

Comment: Estas creando un directorio que ya existe?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea `545` del archivo `usuarios.controlador.php`?

Comment: esta es la linea

Comment: if(!empty($_POST["fotoActual"])){

                        unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);

                    }else{

                        mkdir($directorio, 0755);

                    }

Comment: Que se supone que viaja en editarUsuario? No está en el form, así que no sabemos qué trae y por qué podría duplicarse para diferentes usuarios (porque el error es claro, el directorio ya existe). Como sugerencia, yo no mandaría la fotoActual como variable hidden y validaría en el lado del servidor si el usuario ya tiene una foto, con una consulta o algo por el estilo...

Answer (score 0):

Las mejores validaciones para una peticion tipo post es usando isset , te dejo un ejemplo .

```
 if(isset($_POST["fotoActual"])){
   
    unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);
     

 }else{

    mkdir($directorio, 0755);

  }
```